# Changing value within a Tensor (torch)

Tags: python, tensor, torch

I am in a situation where I have to change the value within the gotten tensor from the model when it is 0.

The problem is that the type of my tensor is from type `grad_fn=<DivBackward0>`. It is a single value in a tensor (so like `tensor([[val]])`)

When I tried using the advice to use `assign()` I got an error saying: `type torch tensor does not have an attribute assign()`.

Does anyone have an idea how I could fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

i have done something like this

```
#created a random tensor like you mention  
x = torch.unsqueeze(torch.randn(1, requires_grad=True),0) / torch.randn(1)
print(x)   #tensor([[0.5953]], grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)

x.data = torch.zeros(1,1)

print(x) # tensor([[0.]], grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
```

Hence i was able to change its content
**NOTE** : This is a signature solution. You can change the vaue as per your need, here i have assigned it to zero